# django - many to many field as dropdown on form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a many to many relationship model which actually shows as a multi select list on forms. In one particular place I want to show it as dropdown single selection - any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

See the documentation on [overriding default field types or widgets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets).

If you've got a `Book` model, with a `ManyToMany` relationship to `Author`, like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=TITLE_CHOICES)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

then you can do something like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Select

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        widgets = {
            'name': Select(),
        }
```

NB. This code is not tested, but will hopefully be enough to get you on your way.